# Img element fixed alignment left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an image element have a fixed alignment, no matter the screen size. I want it to stay left. I have tried many things, including float, horizontal-align and margin-left, but those are hard-coded values, and I want a solution that will ensure that the image will attractively stay left, no matter the screen size. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my HTML:

```
<img class="profile" src="image.jpg" />
```

and here's my CSS:

```
.profile {
position: absolute;
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
margin-left: -300px;
top: 100px;
}
```

It might also be worth mentioning that there are no elements besides the img on the page.

Comment: Have you tried `left` instead of `margin-left`?

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kc6f9vkg/)

Comment: an element by default is formatted to the left although I'm not sure how attractive it is.

Comment: thank you so much alireza safian!

Comment: @user3196429 Wou are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

use   `position: fixed;`

```css
html,body{
    height: 1300px; 
}

.profile {
    position: fixed;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img class="profile" src="image.jpg" />
```

Place the `<img>` tag under **`body`**